# Custom Post Type Fields

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field

I am very interested in creating a coupon plugin for Wordpress, where many of the existing options do not meet my current needs. I have build the core plugin and it is working as expected now so I feel like I am getting close to accomplishing this task.

The problem is that I would like to implement custom fields into the plugin and have them easily set by the authors. These would be things like coupon code, discount amount, expiration date, etc. This plugin (coupon creator) seems to have the layout I am looking for on the Post page, but I have been unable to figure out how its done, where these do not appear to be the "Custom Fields" shown in other tutorials.

How would I go about replacing the large WYSIWIG Editor box with fields like this instead for my CPT?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by not including ["editor" in the "supports" argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

And then add a new meta box using [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) in whose call back you can add all the post meta's as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [My Meta Box](https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box). With this code you can create custom metabox with custom fields includes file uploads, WYSIWIG Editor.

Demo usage is [here](https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box/blob/master/class-usage-demo.php)